# open a file through URL in Win8 store app after build the package

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I want to open a file through URL in Win8 store app.
Below is the code.

```
var uri = new Uri(uriToLaunch);
var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions(); 
options.TreatAsUntrusted = false;
var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri, options);
```

Actually, the code runs well in the debug mode. And in that way, the file is opened.

The problem is, when I build the package, and re-install it through the package, the file won't open. I tracked the success value, and it returns false.
The same thing happens when I try to open a file locally, it can be opened from the debug mode, but failed after building to a package.

Anyone has the experience to resolve it?

Comment: The code run well in Visual Studio, both debug mode and release mode. But when I uninstall the app and re-install it through package, the file won't be open. I have tried different uri, including a file from LAN, a file from Local, and an image from web. All of these can be done in VS, but none of them can be open by the app installed by package. Other functions are perfectly good, including the main page and the tile.

Comment: I think I have the same issue. The only thing that seems to fix it is adding a UI interaction (show message dialog, or have a button) that launches your code.

Answer (score 1):

Direct file/folder access is restricted in an Windows Store app. it is a sandboxed execution environment. There are designated folders that you can use to create and access files. for anything else you will need end user intervention.

look at classes: StorageFolder::GetFileAsync, StorageFile::OpenAsync and DataReader::LoadAsync.